# Insert image after table

Tags: tables, graphics, positioning

I've a problem, I need to insert some image after a table in the same page, I try to set the `table [t]`, `[ht]` but the image go always on top. I don't understand where is the problem.

```
\begin{document}
Blablabla
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}
        {
            \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
                \caption{Configuration}
                \centering
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|l|l|l|l|}
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\ \hline
                & $Run_{1}$ & $Run_{2}$ & $Run_{3}$ &$Run_{4}$ \\ \hline 
                Anomalie  & 5811 & 4266 & 4723 & 5477  \\ \hline
                Accuracy & 96\%  & 72\%  & 78\%  & 91\% \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}
            \end{minipage}
        }

    \end{table}\vspace{3.5cm}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{minipage}[hb]{7.0cm}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=6.8cm]{./run1.png}
            \caption{Run 1}
        \end{minipage}
        \ \hspace{1mm} \hspace{2mm} \
        \begin{minipage}[hb]{7.0cm}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=6.8cm]{./run2.png}
            \caption{Run 2}
        \end{minipage}
        \ \hspace{1mm} \hspace{2mm} \
        \begin{minipage}[hb]{7.0cm}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=6.8cm]{./run3.png}
            \caption{Run 3}
        \end{minipage}
        \ \hspace{1mm} \hspace{2mm} \
        \begin{minipage}[hb]{7.0cm}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=6.8cm]{.run4.png}
            \caption{Run 4}
        \end{minipage}

    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39019#39019

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a *full* minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem.... starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what are you trying to accomplish with `%        \resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}`?

Comment: I use it for resize the dimension of the minipage who contain the table. P.S. I modify [h] or [ht] with [H] but it's the same.

Comment: You need `\usepackage{float}` for `H` to work, did you add that? Further, the way you're trying to do that resizing doesn't actually make much sense. The width of the `minipage` is `\textwidth`, and you're resizing it to `\textwidth`, so you're not really doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to get what you want is to ommit the environments `table` and `figure`, which creates floats. To get a caption for your image and table you need to load package `caption` and use the command `\captionof{figure}` or `\captionof{table}`.

So with the following MWE (see importand code changings marked with `<=====`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}
Blablabla

%   \begin{table}[ht]
        %\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}
        %{
            \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
                \captionof{table}{Configuration} % <====================
                \centering
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|l|l|l|l|}
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\ \hline
                & $Run_{1}$ & $Run_{2}$ & $Run_{3}$ &$Run_{4}$ \\ \hline 
                Anomalie  & 5811 & 4266 & 4723 & 5477  \\ \hline
                Accuracy & 96\%  & 72\%  & 78\%  & 91\% \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}
            \end{minipage}
        %}

%   \end{table}
    \vspace{3.5cm}
%   \begin{figure}
\noindent % <===========================================================
        \begin{minipage}[hb]{7.0cm}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=6.8cm]{./run1.png}
            \captionof{figure}{Run 1} % <===============================
        \end{minipage}
        \ \hspace{1mm} \hspace{2mm} \
        \begin{minipage}[hb]{7.0cm}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=6.8cm]{./run2.png}
            \captionof{figure}{Run 2} % <===============================
        \end{minipage}
        \ \hspace{1mm} \hspace{2mm} \
        \begin{minipage}[hb]{7.0cm}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=6.8cm]{./run3.png}
            \captionof{figure}{Run 3} % <===============================
        \end{minipage}
        \ \hspace{1mm} \hspace{2mm} \
        \begin{minipage}[hb]{7.0cm}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=6.8cm]{.run4.png}
            \captionof{figure}{Run 4} % <===============================
        \end{minipage}

%   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

you get the following resulting page:

[image: resulting pdf]